# gnuplot: only integer values on axis x

Tags: integer, gnuplot, granularity

How can I visualize on axis x only the integer values?

I plot the function described in a file like this

```
0   0.5
1   0.25
2   0.125
3   0.0625
4   0
```

whit these commands:

```
set xrange [0:4]
plot "./data_file" using 1:2 with line lw 2
```

The problem is that, by doing so, I visualize on axis x the values 0; 0.5; 1; 1.5; 2; 2.5; 3; 3.5; 4
How can I visualize only the integer values 0; 1; 2; 3; 4?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
help set

help set xtics

set xtics 1
```

as mgilson notes in the comments, `set xtics` with a single argument defines an increment for the x axis.

Comment: It might be useful to note that `1` corresponds to `<incr>` in the documentation.